# Swift UIView "Empty Image"

Tags: swift, user-interface, uiview

Could someone explain me the difference between these two pictures please?

Code with preview of the UIView:
[image: Code with preview]

Code without the preview of the UIView:
[image: Code without preview]
What's the difference? And why can't I get a preview on the second code example? It only shows "empty image"....

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a "feature" (bug) of a Swift playground. If you don't create the view instance using a non-zero frame width and height, you will get "empty image".

This works:

```
let rect = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
rect.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
rect.backgroundColor = .green
```

But this doesn't:

```
let rect = UIView(frame: .zero)
// also bad: let rect = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 0))
rect.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
rect.backgroundColor = .green
```

And remember that:

```
let rect = UIView()
```

is essentially the same as doing:

```
let rect = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

So when using a playground, create a view with a non-zero frame width and height in the initializer if you don't want to see "empty image".